# Guardians are not spawning

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was about to build a big guardian farm and I wanted to check it with a small one before I waste my time in the big one. So I built a 16X14 room. The water source is at 59th level and the roof is at 60. There are 2 flowing water layer at 58 and 57. The fence gate layer (opened) is at 56th level. The caves below are not lit yet. Not even a single guardian is spawning. I did afk at level 144 but still no use. The room is within the boundaries of the sea temple.

Apart from that I have a skybase exactly above that area which has one cow spawner. Is that a reason for it?

Comment: You say you have a cow spawner, what mods are you playing with? Also, are you sure you have built the farm in the correct location? (They don't work just anywhere)

Comment: im playing on a server and i have a custom cow spawner. im sure that the location is correct

Comment: Is the server in Peaceful difficulty? Are there any configurations that make hostile mobs not spawning?

Comment: Is your query simply whether your skybase is the reason for this problem? That is the only question you actually ask.

Answer (score 1):

Your server may have disabled or not have the capability to spawn Guardians. Some servers are still in 1.7.10 but allow 1.8 clients to join which prevents Guardians from spawning. The server may also have disabled Guardians to balance gameplay. Have you seen any Guardians on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on PlanetMinecraft:

So this video is a really nice and easy way to farm up the new 1.8 gaurdians, get the new blocks, and even get fish! So it relies on the gaurdian spawning range from the temple... which you will need to tear down. The temple has a certain spawning range from the center, so be sure to clear enough water around the temple so that you can have the maximum spawn rates! Have fun and get lots of stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Are you building it in (or very near) the temple? if not it won't work.